# OpenSSL segfault

Tags: c++, openssl, segmentation-fault

I have this simple program:

```
int main ()
{
        /* INITIALIZING OPENSSL */
        SSL_library_init();          
        SSL_load_error_strings();
        ERR_load_BIO_strings();
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

        BIO *bio;
        connectServerSSL(bio);
        login(bio);
}
```

And this functions:

```
void connectServerSSL (BIO *bio)
{
    SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    SSL * ssl;

    if(! SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, "/etc/ssl/certs"))
    {
        callError(ERR_LOADCERT);
    }

    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, hostnamePort);
    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0)
    {
        callError(ERR_CONNECTION);
    }

    if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
    {
        callError(ERR_VALIDCERT);
    }
}
```

When I use this:

> BIO_write(bio, request.c_str(), request.size())

In function connectServerSSL it works OK.

But when i want to use it in some other function:

```
void login (BIO *bio)
{
     BIO_write(bio, request.c_str(), request.size());
}
```

I get Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: You're not returning your `bio` from `connectServerSSL`.

Comment: How can I do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++, even pointers are passed by value. So you need to either change the parameter of connectServerSSL to a BIO *& or else redefine it in the C-style of things:

```
void connectServerSSL (BIO ** bio_ptr)
{
    SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    SSL * ssl;

    if(! SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, "/etc/ssl/certs"))
    {
        callError(ERR_LOADCERT);
    }

    BIO * bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, hostnamePort);
    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0)
    {
        callError(ERR_CONNECTION);
    }

    if(SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
    {
        callError(ERR_VALIDCERT);
    }
    *bio_ptr = bio;
}

// Example usage:

void example()
{
    BIO * bio;
    connectServerSSL(&bio);
    BIO_write(bio, request.c_str(), request.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `connectServerSSL()` function has a parameter named `bio`, and it writes only to this temporary variable, not to the `bio` variable in `main()`, which is uninitialized.

Change the signature of `connectServerSSL()` to `BIO* connectServerSSL(void)` and call it with `bio = connectServerSSL()`.  You could also call the function with a `BIO** newbio` argument, call it with `&bio`, and set `*newbio`, which will update the `bio` variable in `main()`.

Some good habits to help avoid bugs like this: initialize your variables to default values, use assertions to check that your inputs are valid, and single-step through in a debugger.  If you’d initialized the variable in `main()` to `BIO* bio = NULL`, or better yet, `BIO* const bio = connectServerSSL()`, then it would have been obvious in the debugger that it was still uninitialized on return.